# boto3 error: object has no attribute

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Got error when executing the simple code

```
#!/usr/bin/pyhon

import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
res = ec2.describe_instances()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ec2.py", line 6, in 
>     res = ec2.describe_instances()
>     AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'describe_instances'

Can anyone explain the exact cause of the same error. How can I get all the methods described in the following link to work

https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

Below is the aws version installed in my test enviormnet

> aws --version
>   aws-cli/1.11.83 Python/2.7.9 Linux/3.19.0-79-generic botocore/1.5.46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `boto3`, resources are high-level wrappers around the API calls. For direct access to the API methods, change `boto3.resource('ec2')` to `boto3.client('ec2')`.